# How to replace '= ' with '=none'

Tags: powershell, replace, ps

i have this noempty.txt

```
Caption=http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3150513

CSName=DC04

Description=Update

FixComments=

HotFixID=KB3150513

InstallDate=

InstalledBy=NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

InstalledOn=11/29/2022

Name=

ServicePackInEffect=

Status=
```

for example the line "FixComments=" or "InstallDate=" or "name=" i have to add in every line the word "none"

I try whit

```
(Get-Content -Path c:\path\noempty.txt) | ForEach-Object {$_ -Replace '=\s', '=NONE'} | Set-Content -Path c:\path\noempty2.txt
```

But it doesn't work

Any advice?
Thank you very much
Alex

```
(Get-Content -Path c:\path\noempty.txt) | ForEach-Object {$_ -Replace '=\s', '=NONE'} | Set-Content -Path c:\path\noempty2.txt
```

for example the line "FixComments=" or "InstallDate=" or "name=" i have to add in every line the word "none"

Comment: try this one, I think it should work in this case: `(Get-Content path\to\file.txt -Raw) -replace '=(?!\S)', '=NONE'`

Comment: If you stream the content (no `-Raw`), you will need to look for the end (`$`) of the input string (line): `(Get-Content .\NoEmpty.txt) -Replace '=\s*$', '=NONE'`

Comment: `-replace '=$','=NONE'` if nothing is after the =, $ means end of line

Answer (score 1):

You could read the whole file, match the parts that you are interested in and using the full match with `$0` followed by `NONE` in the replacement.

```
$pattern = "(?m)^[^\s=]+=[\p{Zs}\t]*$"
(Get-Content c:\path\noempty.txt -Raw) -replace $pattern, '$0NONE'
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?m)` Inline modifier to enable multiline
- `^` Start of string
- `[^\s=]+` Match 1+ times a non whitespace character except for `=`
- `=` Match literally
- `[\p{Zs}\t]*` Match optional horizontal whitespace characters
- `$` End of string

See the [regex matches](https://regex101.com/r/NyEyAr/1).

Output

```
Caption=http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3150513

CSName=DC04

Description=Update

FixComments=NONE

HotFixID=KB3150513

InstallDate=NONE

InstalledBy=NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

InstalledOn=11/29/2022

Name=NONE

ServicePackInEffect=NONE

Status=NONE
```

---

If you don't want to keep possible trailing spaces after the equals sign, you can use a capture group, and that group 1 in the replacement instead of the whole match:

```
$pattern = "(?m)^([^\s=]+=)[\p{Zs}\t]*$"
(Get-Content c:\path\noempty.txt -Raw) -replace $pattern, '$1NONE'
```

See the [group 1 matches](https://regex101.com/r/VdAFxS/1).